# Importar eventos em formato JSON do Google calendar

Tags: php, json, google-calendar

Quero importar eventos de um Google Calendar não privado do lado do servidor (PHP) em formato JSON.

Uma vez que só quero receber informação e não preciso de editar/criar eventos presumo existir uma maneira que não precise de autentificação.

Sei que é possivel via iCal fazer download de um ficheiro com os dados do calendário com a syntax: `http://www.google.com/calendar/ical/{ID}/public/basic.ics`, e que funciona no meu caso.

Porem queria obter o mesmo mas em formato JSON e via PHP. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Por favor, poderia fornecer um `{ID}` para que eu possa testar?

Comment: @PauloRoberto: o __[link para o iCal](https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/7vfiqps021461t04d4nf6cb4vk@group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics)__ com um `id` no `url` conforme a syntax descrita em cima

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você apenas precisa dizer para o Google Calendar que você quer um JSON, passando isto como parâmetro, e para resgatar o JSON, utilize a função `file_get_contents()` do PHP.

```php
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/7vfiqps021461t04d4nf6cb4vk@group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json');  
echo $json;
```

Note que você está utilizando o mesmo `{ID}` que usou para buscar o ICS, mas você agora está requisitando um JSON.

Você pode obter informações especificas e detalhadas da Google Developers, sobre o uso de JSON para resgatar informações [Aqui](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/json).

Answer (score 3):

Existem muitos componentes prontos para extrair informação de calendários no formato ICS.

Experimente por exemplo esta classe [PHP iCal Parser](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8433-PHP-Parse-calendar-event-information-in-iCal-format.html). Nota, eu modero este site, mas não fui eu que desenvolvi essa classe.